# mediaelement.js supported formats

Tags: mime-types, mediaelement.js, formats

Can mediaelement.js playback .WAV sound files?

Also, even though these are not specified in mediaelement.js website, since Flash is able to playback these formats, can mediaelement.js possibly playback AAC, M4V, M4A, 3GP, MOV and 3GPP?

How about HTML5 playback of any of the formats mentioned above?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

WAV is generally supported in my experience, but of course this is depending on the user's browser, as with all officially supported formats, too.

Have a look at my web app, with the [WAV example here](http://quir.li), which uses mediaelementjs as player engine.